# Django - Where should signals be placed?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

collection.models.py:

```py
class Collection(Model):
  items = ManyToManyField(Item)
  ...
```

item.models.py

```py
class Item(Model):
  state = OneToOneField('ItemState')
  ...

class ItemState(Model):
  item = ForeignKey('Item')
  ...
```

Structure explanation: An item only has a single state at a time, but the client wants to track its state history.

I want to write a signal that creates a new state when a Collection is created. Due to circular imports, I am separating my signals from my models. Now my question is do I write the signal for the above mentioned under `collection_signals.py` or `item_state_signals.py`.

My guess is that both will work, but what would be the logical place to search for the above mentioned signal? I assumed collection since Collection is the sender, but then again this is about creating states and various models will be creating states (e.g. when a new item gets created that should trigger a new state as well)

Comment: what exactly are your signals doing, you might consider overriding save method instead of using signals

Answer (score 1):

I presume *collection* and *item* are your two **Django Apps**. So, create a module inside the app named ***`signals.py`***. So, there will be two files (ideally)

1. collection/signals.py
2. item/signals.py

> I want to write a signal that creates a new state when a **`Collection`** is created.

So, here the **`sender`** will be the **`Collection`** and ***conventionally***, the corresponding signal will be in **`collection/signals.py`**.

In short, look at your ***sender*** class, check where it belongs and create the signal inside the app.